Is there a second method to finding the magnitude of the displacement of a point between $2$ $t$'s for the vector function $\vec{v}(t)$?
I've been slowly completing Khan Academy's Calculus BC course, and was watching the video titled Planar Motion (with integrals). I was pretty bubbly and happy with myself after making the correct method of answering the following question before hearing Sal's explanation:
A particle moving in the $xy$-plane has velocity vector given by $v(t)=\left(\frac{1}{t+7},t^4\right)$ for time $t\ge0$. At $t=1$, the particle is at the point $(3,4)$.

What is the magnitude of the displacement of the particle between $t = 1$ and $t=3$?

My and Sal's method was taking the definite integral between $t = 1$ and $t=3$ of the $x$-component and $y$-component respectively, and then applying the Pythagorean theorem to find $||\vec{p}(t)|| = \sqrt{{\Delta x}^2 + {\Delta y}^2}$.
Upon scrolling down and reading the comments, I came across George Winslow's, which reads:

I seem to recall being able to do this in Calc III 15 years ago by taking the integral of $y\cdot dx$. The explanation was basically that the vast majority of integrals in single variable calculus are set up that way.
In the case of this problem, $y$ would be $t^4$, and $x$ would be $\frac{1}{t+7}$, so that $\frac{dx}{dt}$ would be $\ln|t+7|$ and $dx = \ln|t+7|dt$. Note: this is untrue, $\frac{dx}{dt}$ should be $-\frac{1}{(t+7)^2}$ 
It follows that $y\cdot dx$ would be $t^4 \cdot \ln|t+7|dt$. 
For this problem, of course, that seems like a difficult integral to find. I was going to try to confirm it on my own without asking, but I ran into trouble here. (...)

I was hugely intrigued, it seemed relatively simple, and I love discovering new ways of doing stuff anyway, but the way George Winslow phrases it saying "the vast majority of integrals in single variable calculus are set up that way." confused me a bit, so I was hoping to find a video or an article delving deeper into this.
Only, I was unable to. Googling "planar motion displacement y$*$dx" or "finding displacement for vector function y$*$dx" only yielded me with the original method.
My request: If anybody knows about this alternative method, I would highly appreciate it if you can provide me with an explanation and also further material if you can find any so I can dig in it deeper!
Thank you in advance!

If $x(t) = \frac{1}{t+7}$, then $dx/dt$ is not $\ln|t+7|$.

Yes, I've noticed that he made a mistake in his calculation, I will clarify it in an edit.

I don't believe there is any such method.
First of all, the correct way (which I believe you already know):
Displacement: $$\vec s = \int_{t_1}^{t_2}\vec {v(t)}dt = \int_{t_1}^{t_2}x(t)dt \hat i + \int_{t_1}^{t_2}y(t)dt \hat j$$
So magnitude of displacement:
$$|\vec s| = \sqrt{\left(\int_{t_1}^{t_2}x(t)dt\right)^2 + \left(\int_{t_1}^{t_2}y(t)dt\right)^2}$$
Now, $\int_{x_1}^{x_2} ydx$ gives you the area under the curve - more precisely, between the curve and the $x$-axis between points $(x_1,y_1)$ at $t_1$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ at $t_2$. I cannot immediately see how this is related to the displacement or the magnitude of displacement.
What may be happening here is confusion with the scalar distance travelled by the particle, which involves finding the arc length along the path taken.
Here, what you're finding (distance $d$) is ($x_2 > x_1$):
$$d = \int_{x_1}^{x_2}\sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}dx$$
which can be written ($t_2 > t_1$), like so:
$$d = \int_{t_1}^{t_2}\left(\sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}\right)^2}\right)\left|\frac{dx}{dt}\right|dt \\= \int_{t_1}^{t_2}\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2}dt$$
which will allow you to compute immediately using the given time parametrization.

Thank you for your thoughts! I'm aware of the distance/arc length formula, but I'm a little confused on how it is possibly related/confused with $y \cdot dx$. I'll accept your answer after a week to see if anyone else has anything to say.
